# Why I'm getting "'Aggregate operations can only be used on RLMArray properties'"?

Tags: ios, realm

I have the following query on my `Realm` database

```
realm.objects(Event)
     .filter("ANY presentation.speakers.lastName CONTAINS [c]%@", searchTerm)
```

Unfortunately it's not working, I'm getting the following error

> 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Aggregate operations can only be used on RLMArray properties'

`presentation` is an optional entity defined like this on `Event` class

```
public dynamic var presentation : Presentation?
```

`speakers` is a `List<PresentationSpeakers>` defined like this on presentation

```
public let speakers = List<PresentationSpeaker>()
```

My feeling is that `ANY` must operate directly over a collection but `speakers` is not a direct property of `Event`.

What's wrong with my query and how can I implement it correctly?

Comment: This is a little late, but Realm now supports explicitly having an "ANY" keyword now: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3216

Comment: @jpsim A little late for him, but not for me ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `presentation` is a to-one relationship, there's no need to write `ANY` in your query:

```
realm.objects(Event)
     .filter("presentation.speakers.lastName CONTAINS [c]%@", searchTerm)
```

The `ANY` is implicit for the `speakers` property because it is a nested keypath. To specify something other than `ANY`, you would use a modifier on `speakers` like this:

```
realm.objects(Event)
     .filter("presentation.speakers[FIRST].lastName CONTAINS [c]%@", searchTerm)
```

However, Realm doesn't support this kind of query yet.

For more information on predicates and which ones are support by Realm, see Realm's predicate cheat sheet: https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: It turns out that the predicate you shared is valid, but that Realm doesn't support it at the moment. I just filed a GitHub issue on Realm's repository: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2955. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks :)